# How big was the Slitheen family?

Tags: doctor-who, aliens, the-sarah-jane-adventures

In Doctor Who season one (2005), we're introduced to a family of aliens called the "Slitheen". The species name for the Slitheen is "Raxacoricofallapatorian", but we only ever see one example of aliens from outside the Slitheen family (the *Blathereen* family, Sarah Jane Adventures, "The Gift").

This lead to many viewers assuming that "Slitheen" was the name of the entire race, not a single family- an easy mistake to make, when you consider how frequently they appear throughout the show.

For them to appear so frequently on the show, (often getting "vinegared" and killed by the protagonists) the family had to be unusually large, but just how large was the Slitheen family?

Comment: "the family had to be unusually large" — Unusual by whose definition?

Comment: @Quentin I suppose I can't really hold it to earthly standards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be more helpful to think of the Slitheen as a clan, as opposed to a family.   The members we saw in Aliens of London were from the Passameer-Day branch of the Slitheen clan, and the ones from The Lost Boy (on SJA) were from the Lutiven-Day Branch.